"Not finding what you're looking for" UI component on every page - where should I position it?
I'd like to add a "Not finding what you're looking for" section to each page on a commercial web site, with guidance what the user should do, if they had not found whatever the had been looking for. One of the top reasons to add such a component is that most pages would be visited by users who landed directly from Google, instead of navigating all the way from the home page and having clear idea where they came from and where they are heading towards.
I cannot figure out, though, what is the logical (intuitive) place for this component. My dilemma is:

If I put it after the page level content (the 1st option), it seems out of place to me, because it is supposed to be a global navigation element. Global navigation on this page is the header, breadcrumb, footer and this element. As such it should be visually consistent with all the rest global navigation elements, that is, visually it should merge with the footer, adjacent just below. That is, the 2nd option would be more appropriate.
But then, users have tunnel vision when looking for specific information on a web page and I am afraid they wouldn't pay attention to the global navigation elements. With this reasoning in mind, I should keep it visually consistent with the main page content style and position it there, as well.
To help you get the idea better, imagine this was a vacuum cleaners web site. You are looking for a specific vacuum cleaner model and googling it, landed you on a page. Not seeing it immediately, you could either hit "search" (if present on the page), or browse categories and filters (if present, again) and if you are still not finding that particular model, where would you expect to see such aiding UI component?

I believe the feature that you're trying to implement is pretty redundant.
When customer clicks on your ecommerce website, on average you have less than a minute to make sure that this customer finds the product of interest. By the time customer has made through the search or categories, you've most likely already lost the customer's patience.
Anyway, if you still think to implement it, I believe that putting this table into the footer won't solve this issue, as footer links are rarely clicked (compared to categories, sidebar and search). I'd rather use this table in the product page after all the relevant information regarding product, or somewhere in the sidebar as an accordion :)

What type of research method & plan would you propose to test your assumptions?
